# machine learning in rapidminer(select by weights operator)

Tags: rapidminer

How can I provide input to the wei port of select by weight operator manually using an excel sheet.I tried the below format
attribute weight

```
rlndc.opr.l_hub_centr   0.8829047139
frntl.inf.orb.r_hub_centr   0.8750850468
spp.mtr.ar.l_hub_centr  0.8646401198
frntl.md.r_hub_centr    0.8620028802
cdt.r_hub_centr 0.8334183679
frntl.inf.tr.l_hub_centr    0.8289782694
rlndc.opr.r_hub_centr   0.8274914408
```

I am getting the error"expected attribute but received example set"

Answer (score 0):

The `Select by Weights` operator requires a weights object. You can create one of these using the operator `Data to Weights` which takes an example set and creates a weights object with the weights all set to 1. You can write this to a file by using `Write Weights` and you can then edit this file to have the weights you want (it's an XML file with a specific format hence the need to write it correctly). Finally, you can use `Read Weights` to read in the edited file and have the weights object you need. This can be connected to `Select by Weights`.